# ACODE - spoj: Suggest what might be wrong with my approach

Tags: dynamic-programming, top-down

I tried this question ACODE from spoj. If you could suggest me, what might be wrong with my approach!
Link to the question: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACODE/

My approach:

```
typedef long long ll;
ll dp[27][3];

ll acode(char *A,int n,int k)
{
    if(k==0)
    {
        ll x,y;
        x=acode(A,n,1);
        y=acode(A,n,2);
        return (x+y);
    }
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==0)
    {
        if(k==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    if(dp[n][k] != 0)
        return dp[n][k];
    int m;
    if(k==1)
        m=A[n]-'0';
    else
        m=10*(A[n-1]-'0')+(A[n]-'0');
    if(m<27 && m!=0)
    {
        if(k==1)
            dp[n][k] = acode(A,n-1,1)+acode(A,n-1,2);
        else
            dp[n][k] = acode(A,n-2,1)+acode(A,n-2,2);
    }
    return dp[n][k];
}

int main()
{
    char A[5001];
    cin>>A;
    cout<<A;
    while(strcmp(A,0))
    {   
        int l = strlen(A);
        cout<<acode(A,l-1,0)<<endl;
        cin>>A;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using top-down DP.Memoization of each index value for k=1 or k=2.

Comment: Is there a problem or error, or are you just looking for feedback on your code?

Comment: It wasn't working, and i thought there might be an optimized approach for the problem. I was able to come up with this solution only.
Anyway I applied some changes, and it worked. Will look to optimize it now.

Comment: If you're looking for optimisation and feedback then this question should go on the Code Review Stack Exchange site. If you're no longer looking for an answer here then I would recommend deleting the question, or if you've still got a question then edit it.

Comment: I found the nice implementation without any extra space here http://www.kodemonk.com/acode-alphacode/

Comment: yup thanks! @codeomnitrix